# Recover Tables by .ibd and .frm Files

Tags: mysql, dump

Yesterday I've spent my time to find a solution to recover various DB from .ibd and .frm files..

Finally,I've found this solution (?):

https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb

They have a [website](https://recovery.twindb.com/) when I've take a test and the software have found the table structure, and the values..!
But I can't take 99$ for this minimal dumps..!

In the chat, they advised me that this is free solution:

https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb

I've installed VirtualBox with an ISO of Centos 7, I've cloned this git and I've installed this libraries **make**, **gcc**, **flex** and **bison**.

Now I'm reading this tutorial to recover my tables:

https://twindb.com/recover-after-drop-table-innodb_file_per_table-is-on/

But at this point:

> root@test:/var/lib/mysql/sakila# ll

When I write `[root@localhost]#/root/backups/mysql/relinko# ll`
The terminal take to me this error:

```
bash: /root/backups/mysql/relinko# File or directory not exist
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

`ll` is a common alias in bash shell on CentOS and Ubuntu distributions.

```
$ alias ll 
alias ll='ls -alF'
```

I guess it's not defined in your shell on whatever reason. I updated [the post](https://twindb.com/recover-after-drop-table-innodb_file_per_table-is-on/) to be less confusing.